# Attach an event listener to a class to listen for events from its members

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, eventemitter

I have two classes: `EventEmitter` and `EventCatcher`. The `EventCatcher` has 2 members of `EventEmitter`. `EventEmitter` emits a test event. In the catcher I want to catch all test events and do something:

EventEmitter

```
var events = require('events');
var sys = require('util');

module.exports = eventEmit;

function eventEmit(name) {
    this.name = name;
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
}

sys.inherits(eventEmit, events.EventEmitter);

eventEmit.prototype.emitTest = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.emit('test');
}
```

EventCatcher

```
var eventEmit = require('./eventEmit');

module.exports = eventCatch;

function eventCatch() {
    this.eventEmitA = new eventEmit("a");
    this.eventEmitB = new eventEmit("b");
    this.attachHandler();
}

eventCatch.prototype.attachHandler = function()  {
    //I want to do something like:
    // this.on('test', function() };

    this.eventEmitA.on('test', function() {
        console.log("Event thrown from:\n" + this.name);
    });
    this.eventEmitB.on('test', function() {
        console.log("Event thrown from:\n" + this.name);
    });
};

eventCatch.prototype.throwEvents = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.eventEmitA.emitTest();
    self.eventEmitB.emitTest();
};
```

Is there a way to attach X events to the `EventCatcher` class in `attachHandler`, without having to manually attach for each `EventEmitter` class?

Comment: there's no question mark in your question. if you're looking for a better way to implement this, you'd probably want to post this on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There's no better way, this is the only way to catch events.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var eventEmit = require('./eventEmit');

module.exports = eventCatch;

function eventCatch() {
    this.emitters = [];
    this.emitters.push(new eventEmit("a"));
    this.emitters.push(new eventEmit("b"));
    this.on('test', function() {
        console.log("Event thrown from:\n" + this.name);
    });
}

eventCatch.prototype.on = function(eventName, cb) {
    this.emitters.forEach(function(emitter) {
        emitter.on(eventName, cb);
    });
};

eventCatch.prototype.throwEvents = function() {
    this.emitters.forEach(function(emitter) {
        emitter.emitTest();
    });
};
```

This written is from mind, so I don't really know if the scope is correct inside the callback.